# vb.net populate datagridview with combodropbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I initialized a dataset from an array. I want to display this on a datagridview. In which I just use datasource property to the dataset and it's working. however, one of the column needs to be a dropdown, how can I initialize the datagridview to have the dropdown values, then when I set it to the dataset, the value on that column is also selected.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to your grid. The code below is a method I use for adding one to a DataGridView so isn't exactly what you want but should help you along:

```
Public Sub AddComboBoxColumn(Dgv As DataGridView, ByVal fieldName As String, ByVal heading As String, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal DataSource As Object, Optional ByVal ValueMember As String = "Id", Optional ByVal DisplayMember As String = "Desc")
    Dim col As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    With col

        .DataSource = DataSource
        .ValueMember = ValueMember
        .DisplayMember = DisplayMember

        .DataPropertyName = fieldName
        .Name = fieldName
        .HeaderText = heading
        .Visible = True
        .Width = width
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
        .ReadOnly = False
        If Not .ReadOnly Then .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
        .DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue = ""

    End With

    Dgv.Columns.Add(col)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, It adds a dropdown column, however, after calling datagridview.datasource = dataset, I just ended-up with a new dropdown column that is doing nothing. how can I associate the new column to one of the field in dataset?

Comment: @Gilbert you need to set the DataPropertyName property on the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to the field name in the dataset to map it.